# Sidenav Dropdowns Conflicting

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to have a dropdown navigation system, however, I am unable to have both dropdowns open at the same time. Despite hours of looking I can't seem to find a way to achieve this.

Any help is much appreciated.

My HTML;

```
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <link type="text/css" href="F:\Revision Website\Styling\Stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="F:\Revision Website\Scripts\Main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <header>
        <h1>Home</h1>
    </header>

    <nav>
        <div class="navbar">
            <a href="F:\Revision Website\Webpages\Index.html">Home</a>

            <button class="dropbtn" onclick="showFunction()">Computing</button>
                <div class="dropdownContainer" id="content">
                    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                </div>

            <button class="dropbtn" onclick="showFunction()">Physics</button>
                <div class="dropdownContainer" id="content">
                    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <article>
        <p></p>
    </article>

</body>
```

My JS;

```
function showFunction() {
    document.getElementById("content").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdownContainer");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
            if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT

The following code "works" however, only through use of internal JS, which I rather not use.

```
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropbtn");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");

    var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
        dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
    }
});
}
```

Comment: `id`s should be _unique_

Answer (score 0):

Please Use

```
     <button class="dropbtn" onclick="showFunction(this)">Physics</button>
```

and javascript

```
   function showFunction(ele) {
    $(ele).find('#content').classList.toggle("show");
   }
```

i think this would be help

Comment: Didn't work, using that code only stops the dropdowns working at all, as opposed to conflicting.